# Tabulating Database Data

Tags: php, html, mysql

My PHP Code :

```
echo '<table style="width:700px; padding-left: 0px;" cellspacing="12">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#E7EBF2">';
Echo $info['header'];
echo '</br>

<a href="get-page.php?name='.$info['name'].'">
<img src="path/'.$info['image'] .'"></a> <br>'; 
echo '</td><tr></table>';
} 
?>
```

When i output the database data, the images are displaying in down wise .
i want to display images ,such that a row contains two images (two columns).
how to code in php/html ,such that the first two images are displayed in first row ?

[image]

And wanna make the last uploaded image should come to first of the output table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your sql query, order by id DESC to show them in reverse order, then to display two values before creating a new row, you can use:

```
$x = 0;
echo "<table><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";

    //Checks if $x is divisible evenly by 2, and if so, add new row
    if($x % 2)
    {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
$x++;
}
echo "</table>"
```